# using lucene search I need to get hit if search string either phrase or character that exits in field value

Tags: lucene

How do I get search hit like below mentioned scenario using **lucene search**?

Example:
**Hi Hello world**

In above example, if I enter "Hello wo",or "Hel",or "Hello" I need to get a hit.

that means if entered phrase or character exits in search string I need to get hit

Here is my code to get hits:

```
QueryParser parser = null;
Query query = null;
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, new HashSet());
BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(32767);
parser = new QueryParser("fieldname", analyzer);
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
query = parser.parse("searchString");
TopDocs topResultDocs = searcher.search(query, null, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, would just be to create a prefix query by adding a wildcard (`*`) to the end of the search string, like:

```
query = parser.parse("hel*")
```

Alternatively, you might also use an [ngram filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenFilter.html) in your analyzer to split tokens into smaller chunks.

Comment: if i give 'Hello wo' or 'Hello w'  search string with suffix * not gets hit

Comment: TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(field, new StringReader(searchString));
  List tokens = new ArrayList();
  TermAttribute termAttribute = (TermAttribute) tokenStream.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class);

  while (tokenStream.incrementToken())
  {
   String term = termAttribute.term();
   tokens.add(term);
  }
  BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
  {
   booleanQuery.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term(field, tokens.get(i).toString())), Occur.MUST);
  }
  TopDocs topResultDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, null, 20);

Comment: @user3230860 - Obviousy, that's a little difficult to read.  You are, however, allowed, and [*encouraged*, to answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!  If this has solved the problem for you, please do post it as an answer.